# Cubic solving general method

Tags: cubics

I've been trying to solve cubic equations, but I don't know if there is a general approach that always works. Is there a specific method for solving cubics that doesn't involve the cubic formula?

Comment: You can use trigonometry instead.

Comment: There is a general approach that always works - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) (General cubic formula, trigonometric and hyperbolic solutions etc.) Also, search this site for more, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452901/solving-cubic-equations-with-another-method) with an example using trigonometry.